# Scroll does't work properly when aligning in the center of screen (using transform)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to align a div in the center of the screen.
The code works great until I make the screen small, then the scrolling doesn't work properly and it cuts off the top of my centered component (when the centered component height becomes equal or less than screen size)

Any idea About a solution ?!
I'd be happy to use any other approach (without transform) but with none of the approaches I've accomplished to put the div in the center of screen)

```css
.LoginContainer {
  background-color: $base;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.LoginBox {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 5rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="LoginContainer">
  <div class="LoginBox">
      TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-bird-hzood
I've also recreated the issue here. As you can see when the screen size has less height the white component gets clipped.

[Image of the screen when the top part is clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQytZ.png)

[Image of the regular screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEFgQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Would simply centering child components not work:

```
.LoginContainer {
    background-color: $base;
    ...
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Comment: It just centers it horizontally if I remove the fixed positioning and top, bottom, right, left values. and if I don't remove these values the same thing happens(top part gets clipped). Is there anything I'm missing? @jsdeveloper

Comment: did you remove all the other css styling on the loginbox? if so please post codesandbox to highlight the issue

Comment: This is my css now :

```
.LoginContainer {
  background-color: $base;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.LoginBox {
    margin: 1rem;
    max-width: 30rem;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: white;
}

```

 I also added 2 screenshots to my question.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-bird-hzood

I've also recreated the issue here. As you can see when the screen size has less height the white component gets clipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent to be scrollable and the LoginComponent to be scrolled:

```css
.LoginContainer {
  background-color: $base;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.LoginBox {
  padding: 15rem 5rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="LoginContainer">
  <div class="LoginBox">
      TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the LoginComponent to not exceed the boundaries of the parent and make is scrollable:

```css
.LoginContainer {
  background-color: $base;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.LoginBox {
  padding: 15rem 5rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="LoginContainer">
  <div class="LoginBox">
      TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the same result. When screen height is less than div height the top part gets clipped!

Comment: You want the LoginBox to have max-height to be equal to the parent's div and make it scrollable?

Comment: I edited the answer with the case when you want to make the login component scrollable

Comment: No, I don't want the login box to be scrollable. Somehow there is an issue with scrolling the page. I've added 2 photos to my question which may illustrate the issue.
I'm so grateful for your help!

Comment: codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-bird-hzood I've also recreated the issue here. As you can see when the screen size has less height the white component gets clipped.